# Rails and Mongo GridFS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, gridfs

I always used Mongoid as driver, but now I should use Mongo driver to save files to GridFS. I can't understand, how to mixin Mongo to models and where should I put explicit connection code. May you help me?

Comment: By "Mongo driver" do you mean the mongo shell?  You don't need explicit connection code within the shell, it connects at startup.